# Do you think generic properties would be useful in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, c#-3.0, properties

I'm not talking about generic classes that declare properties or fields with the type of a generic parameter. I'm talking about generic properties which could be applied to both generic and non-generic classes.

I'm not talking about this:

```
public class Base<T>
{
    public T BaseProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I'm talking about this:

```
public class Base
{
    public T BaseProperty<T>
    {
       get
       {
          // Insert magic
       }
       set
       {
          // Insert magic
       }
    }
}
```

Or this:

```
public class Base<U>
{
    public T BaseProperty<T>
    {
       get
       {
          // Insert magic
       }
       set
       {
          // Insert magic
       }
    }

    public U OtherBaseProperty { get; set; }
}
```

The usage would go something like this:

```
var b = new Base();
b.BaseProperty<int> = 42;
int i = b.BaseProperty<int>;
b.BaseProperty<string> = "Hi";
string s = b.BaseProperty<string>;
```

Or for the second example:

```
var b = new Base<string>();
b.BaseProperty<int> = 42;
int i = b.BaseProperty<int>;
b.OtherBaseProperty = "Hi";
string s = b.OtherBaseProperty;
```

The // Insert Magic refers to handling each call to the generic property getter or setter that has a different type for the type parameter.

For example this:

```
b.BaseProperty<int> = 42;
```

Needs to be handled differently to:

```
b.BaseProperty<string> = "Hi";
```

I would envisage that for each type T if the getter is called before the setter is called then default(T) is returned.
When the setter is called the value is stored per type T so that when the getter is subsequently called the previous value that was set for that type is returned.

Note that under the covers properties are just methods.

**Do you think this would be useful?**

Comment: No, it does not seem all that useful.  If I need an int property, I'll make one.  If I need a string property, I'll make one.  Pretty simple.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've had a couple of times where I would have liked the ability to do this, yes.

However, the syntax involved would be pretty ugly, and it's sufficiently rarely useful that I think I prefer to just suck it up and go with generic methods.

Comment: Indeed, there's been once or twice when it would have been handy. I asked Mads Torgersen @ MS about this once and he basically said, "Why would you wanna do that?" In other words, the edge cases are not compelling enough.

Comment: These kinds of properties can be implemented using traits: http://scg.unibe.ch/Research/Rotor/index.html, unfortunately for .Net they never made it out of research ...

Comment: Thanks Jon. I'm enjoying your book very much by the way. I was just reading about generics last night and had this idea.

Comment: @Jonathan: Glad your having fun with it - please mail me if you have any feedback, good or bad :)

Comment: @Jon: Will do. P.S. I would love to hear your thoughts on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656564/

Answer (score 1):

No       .

Answer (score 1):

Without a killer use case, no. You can already achieve the same thing with a pair of generic methods, should you need it.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Generic methods make sense, because they embody some (generic) operation that can sensibly be applied to different types.

But properties only make sense as uniquely named values with definite content. 'Generic properties', like you suggest, really only amounts to like-named properties with different signature and different content.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one example where it would have been handy for me, if it would have been possible.

```
var settings = new Settings();  
int timeout = settings<int>["CacheInMinutes"];
```

Where Settings loads an XML file of configuration variables.

That, compared to:

```
var settings = new Settings();  
int timeout = int.Parse(settings["CacheInMinutes"]);
```

Really not much of a difference, but hey, I still would have preferred the generic indexer.

Comment: Yeah but "int timeout = settings.Get<int>("CacheInMinutes");" is just as terse, and doesn't require language change/addition to implement.

Comment: Good one. Indexers look like a good use case:

Session<User>["CurrentUser"] = new User();
...
var user = Session<User>["CurrentUser"];

Answer (score 1):

well, I have the situation that need generic property in non-generic class.

Example you have `IComponent` class that want to provide its parent `IContainer` with property `Parent`, since the component can belong to any container type. so you need to provide generic property rather than generic method

```
Component c = new Component();
Container p = new Container();
p.Add(c);
```

and then you access its parent using generic property (not aplicable now)

```
c.Parent.ContainerProperty;
c.Parent.ContainerMethod();
```

rather using verbose method like

```
c.Parent().ContainerProperty;
c.Parent().ContainerMethod();
```

Well, in this case generic property is more beautiful and make sense, since you don't need to input any argument.

Answer (score 0):

If for some bizarre reason you decided you wanted it, you could sort of fake it with methods:

```
public class Thing
{
    Dictionary<Type, object> xDict = new Dictionary<Type,object>();
    public void set_X<T>(T x)
    {
        xDict[typeof(T)] = x;
    }
    public T get_X<T>()
    {
        return (T)xDict[typeof(T)];
    }
}
```

Why you would want to is an entirely different matter, though. It generally makes more sense to start with something you want to do than some way you want to do it.